# Check liked or shared on facebook for Android

Tags: android, facebook

I was given a requirement where the user shares content on Facebook and gets points in return. Is there a way I could detect if the user shared something?

I'm working only with the info from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android), I have this code:

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("some link"))
            .build();
    ShareButton shareButton = (ShareButton)findViewById(R.id.fb_share_button);
    shareButton.setShareContent(content);
```

The oject in the xml:

```
<com.facebook.share.widget.ShareButton
    android:id="@+id/fb_share_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: if you have `read_stream` permission, you can go through his wall posts.

Comment: Facebook Platform Policy specifically say that you are not allowed to give anything to the user for likes or shares.

Comment: You, and who ever gave you that assignment, need to go read FB [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/). You are not allowed to reward users for posting/liking.

Comment: Thanks for that information